# Wicket: reload AjaxLazyLoadPanel automatically

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a page with a form. Using the data from the form I get information from a BBDD and I displayed in a panel using Ajax.

Now I was trying to use a AjaxLazyLoadPanel, because some of the query in the BBDD are heavy. The problem i have is after the first load of AjaxLazyLoadPanel, i dont know how to reload it with the new content (a new search).

Any advice??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I have not worked with AjaxLazyLoadPanel, but the generic approach to periodically updating a component is attaching an [AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html):

```
add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("myPanel"){
    // implementation here
}
.setOutputMarkupId()
.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(2))));
```

Or, if that does not work, at the behavior to a different component and let the AjaxRequestTarget [add the AjaxLazyLoadPanel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#addComponent%28org.apache.wicket.Component%29) (you might have to attach the AjaxLazyLoadPanel first).

---

Here are a few relevant links about wicket and AJAX:

- [How to do things in Wicket - AJAX](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax.html)
- [How Wicket does AJAX](http://java.dzone.com/news/interview-how-wicket-does-ajax)
- [WicketByExample.com / AJAX](http://wicketbyexample.com/tag/ajax/)
- [How to use AjaxLazyLoadPanel in Wicket](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-use-ajaxlazyloadpanel-in-wicket/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem with Ajax, it's about the image (the little wheel indicating "loading") that shows the first time the AjaxLazyLoadPanel is loaded.

I think I've found a solution:

Add the AjaxLazyLoadPanel in a WebMarkupContainer and in the ajax button that refreshes the content:

```
 // lazy is the WebMarkupContainer
 @Override
 protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

      lazy.replace(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("lazyLoadSearch") {
           @Override
           public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String id) {
                return new SearchPanel(id, rep, searchString, typeOfSearch);
           }
      });

      if (target != null) {
           target.addComponent(lazy);
      }
 }
```

Comment: you should accept your own solution or the question will keep showing up as unanswered